# Are initialization and assignment names for the same thing in Java (the first time but not second time)?

Tags: java, initialization, declaration, assign

Just to get the words clear here in Java.

**Primitive types:**

This is a declaration right:

```
int a;//declared but unitialized
```

Intializations and assignments:

```
a = 1;//intialization and assignment

a = 2;//this is no longer intialization but still an assignment the 2nd time?

int b = 1;//declaration and intialization = assignment combined?

b = 2;//just assignment because 2nd time?
```

**Class types:**

```
String str;//declaration

str = "some words";//this is also an intialization and assignment?

str = "more words"; //since new object still both intialization and assignment even 2nd time?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler considers a variable initialised when it knows the local variable has been set and can be read without error.

Consider this case, where the compiler cannot determine the `a` variable has been initialised.

```
int a;
try {
    a = 1;
    // a is initialised and can be read.
    System.out.println(a); // compiles ok.
} catch (RuntimeException ignored) {
}
// a is not considered initialised as the compiler 
// doesn't know the catch block couldn't be thrown before a is set.
System.out.println(a); // Variable 'a' might not have been initialized

a = 2;
// a is definitely initialised.
System.out.println(a); // compiles ok.
```

Comment: Ok but what about the assignment = initalization ?

Comment: Initialization is just the first assignment to a given variable.

Comment: So in `int a; System.out.println("hello"); a = 1; a = 2;` the assignment of 1 is also an initialisation, even though it's not combined with the declaration.

Comment: Ok so then I am right when I say that the first assignment is also the initialization and the second assigment is not and initialization with primitive types. BUT the first assignment with a stringtype is the initialization and the second assignment is also an initialization since it creates a new object?

Comment: Using a String literal doesn't create a new object. When you initialize a reference, its the reference which is initialized, not the object.

Comment: And to complicate things further, a variable can have been assigned several times but not even initialized (to the compiler in outer scope) if these assignments have been done in local scopes?

Comment: Variables, field, method and class in different scopes are considered different even if they happen to have the same name.

Comment: Ok, ok, you're right. The reference is initialized and that reference is written over the 2nd time 3rd etc and that is not an initalization these times but an assignment, right?

Answer (score 0):

Initialization is first assignment. Always.